# How to access an assigned variables dynamically in freeMarker

Tags: html, apache, html-email, freemarker, email-templates

```
<#assign U="Unknown" B="both" M="male" F="female">

<div>
<span>     ${transaction.addressTransactions.addresses.newInfo.GenderTypeCode.code} </span>
</div>
```

- transaction.addressTransactions.addresses.newInfo.GenderTypeCode.code = This will output either U/B/M/F. I want to use this output and access the corresponding assigned variables.
- For example if transaction.addressTransactions.addresses.newInfo.GenderTypeCode.code returns U, I  want to access the assigned variable and get the value of U which is "Unknown". How can I do that in Freemarker?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like `.vars[myDynamicVariableName]`, however, you may not need that. You could just use `<#assign codeToLabel = { "U": "Unknown", "B": "both", "M": "male", "F": "female" }>` and then `codeToLabel[myDynamicCode]`.